# Finding the equation of a Normal line

Tags: calculus

Here is my problem:
Find the equation of the normal line to the parabola $$y = x^2 - 5x + 4$$ that is parallel to the line $x - 3y = 5.$

I found the slope for the line to be $m = 1/3$.
I found the derivative of the parabola to be $2x - 5$.
I tried equating $2x - 5 = 1/3$ but I dont know if Im heading in the right direction.

Comment: derivative is for slope of tangent

Comment: Yea but the inverse reciprocal of the slope for the tangent line is the slope of the normal line right?

Comment: yes so you should equate $2x-5=-3$

Comment: okay now solve for x and then what?

Comment: you will get the point from which the normal passes through

Comment: what about the y value of the point?

Answer (score 2):

You are heading in the right direction. Continue resolving $2x - 5 = \frac{1}{3}$, where you will find the $x$ point of the line. Then find the $y$ point and use the formula $y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$, being the point you found $(x_1,y_1)$.